# which eigenvalue is the stable one

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

I'm reading a textbook that says something along the lines of, given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$. The Jacobian evaluated at $x_0$ has one eigenvalue smaller than one one eigenvalue greater than one. Then it says $[1 v]$ be  the eigenvector that corresponds to the stable eignvalue. I'm confused now as to shich one is the stable one. Apparently the textbook assumes this is clear, but I'm not too familiar with dynamic systems so I'm not sure.

Comment: Your question is missing context. There are plenty of Jacobians that have eigenvalues both less that $1$, or both greater than $1$, or both complex etc. You'll need to clarify _what_ Jacobian you are talking about. Also, stability is determined by the real part of the eigenvalue.

Comment: I think that providing exact reference is better than just saying *I'm reading a textbook*. (There is a chance that some readers of your post have access to that book and this information can help them getting more context.) I imagine something like: "I am reading Introduction to Perturbation Methods by Holmes. On [page 360](https://books.google.com/books?id=EX5iNglbqB4C&pg=PA360) relation between Jacobian and stability is discussed. The author says in Corollary 6.1 that..." (This is just an example. Although some relevant keywords appear there, the quote is not exactly about your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the unstable manifold $E^u$ of a linear operator corresponds to all eigenvalues of modulus greater than 1, while the stable manifold $E^s$ corresponds to all eigenvalues smaller than 1 in modulus. Perturbations in the $E^s$ direction will decrease (as the eigenvalues are smaller than 1), while perturbations in the $E^u$ direction will increase--hence the names "stable" and "unstable."